# Automatically expiring records in a temporal table?

Tags: sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

I have a need to store some results that are only valid for a rolling 5 day window. An application will insert or update records and the results should be viewable for the 5 day window. However, there potentially is a need to look at how the results were for prior periods. A temporal table sounded great for this as historical I can just use the `SYSTEM_TIME between` clause to look up historical records, and to look at the current 5 day window, I would just leave off the clause.
However, there is a problem let say that some record *I*, was valid last week, but is no longer in the current dataset. Without me adding a step to delete old results *I* will still be in the resulting set as it's `row end` column will always have `9999-12-31`, until it is updated or deleted.
How can I set it to `dateadd(d,5,sysutcdatetime())`?  Setting a default does not seem to work, and I cannot explicitly insert a value either.

> Cannot insert an explicit value into a GENERATED ALWAYS column in table 'my.table'.
> Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the GENERATED ALWAYS column,
> or insert a DEFAULT into GENERATED ALWAYS column.

Note that the hint lies. The default seems to not be used.

Here is a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=42c88e5c8ab0603a6503c10b2361dc90) presenting the problem.

Comment: Couldn't you filter based on when the row was inserted and ignore anything over 5 days?

Comment: While sure, I as the guy working on the database know this fact. An end-user may not. I can write a view and have that permissioned for the end-users and then use instead-of triggers to add the hidden expiry column, but then it's the samething as a temporal table except I have to do all the work.

Answer (score 3):

This is the essence of what it means to be a `system_versioning` temporal table.  You cannot control the `row start` and `row end` values.  If you want the rows to be deleted after 5 days, you'll have to have a job to delete them.